# Why does guix install default to .guix_profile while guix pull defaults to .config/guix/current?

Tags: guix

Guix having multiple profiles as nice but having two different default profiles is confusing and I'm unclear as to what the benefit of having two is supposed to be.  Surely a single default profile would be simpler?  Not clear when GUIX_PROFILE should point to one and when to the other.

Answer (score 0):

The `.config/guix-current` directory contains just the `guix` program itself and the list of packages. Running `guix pull` updates both of these.

The `.guix_profile` directory contains all other packages you install with `guix install`.

I assume that purpose is so that you can share the same `guix` between your main profile and other profiles (eg. `guix install --profile`) as well as allowing upgrade of guix without independently of these profiles.

Comment: I don't see why I couldn't use a guix installed in .guix_profile to upgrade other profiles by passing an appropriate flag.  Likewise since guix doesn't seem to expose dependencies in the profile I don't see why I need a separate profile to upgrade guix independently of other packages in the profile.

Answer (score 0):

I found a post that gives reasons why guix is installed in a separate profile: https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/guix-devel/2016-11/msg01157.html.  The reasons given are that it could cause undesirable behavior where upgrading guix creates a new generation or, theoretically, prevents rollback.  Ensuring that rollback works seems like an adequate reason to me so I guess my question is answered but I'm not sure why creating a new generation is considered undesirable.